# Replace anyType node from List<Object> xml serialization

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

so I'm serializing an object that contains a `List<Object>` property, and it serializes it like this:

```
<Explorer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Explorer1</Name>
  <Items>
    <anyType xsi:type="FolderObject">
      <Name>Folder1</Name>
      <Items>
        <anyType xsi:type="MyObject">
          <Name>Object 1</Name>
        </anyType>
      </Items>
    </anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="MyObject">
      <Name>Object 2</Name>
    </anyType>
  </Items>
</Explorer>
```

So what I want to do is replace the anyType node with some other name. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably need to elaborate on "possible" the result of XMl serialization is a XML element which is basically just a string and string manipulation is possible but I guess that's not what you mean by "possible" if the question is can I change the node name and still make deserialization work the answer is still yes but you'd probably need to supply your own deserializer

Comment: Hmm yeah I want to avoid creating my own deserializer. I was just thinking of using something like XmlAttribute("OtherName"), that didn't work btw, but something similar.

Comment: Please see answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915749/serializing-objects-in-c-sharp-to-xml-can-not-change-anytype-to-move/20915925#20915925

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915749/serializing-objects-in-c-sharp-to-xml-can-not-change-anytype-to-move/20915925#20915925

Answer (score 0):

Have you the the XmlElement attribute on the class?